# How to implement google tag manager code in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a chrome extension that runs on contacts.google.com page. I need to implement google tag manager code in my project but I am not able to add it. As the documentation given at the following link https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart say that we have to add the code at the < Head> tag and < body> tag. The problem is that I do not have html file as the html content is loaded into the google contacts page using javascript files: background.js file and content.js file.
Can someone please tell how to implement google tag manager code in chrome extension ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it
but it worked out for me

on manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    .
    .
    . 
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"], 
      "js": ["jQuery.js","gtm.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    },
    ...
```

on gtm.js

```
const accountToken = `GTM-XXXXX`;
const dataLayer = [];
function integrateGTM() {
  (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({ "gtm.start": new Date().getTime(), event: "gtm.js" });
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j = d.createElement(s),
      dl = l != "dataLayer" ? "&l=" + l : "";
    j.async = true;
    j.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=" + i + dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
  })(window, document, "script", "dataLayer", accountToken);
  const code = `<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=${accountToken}"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>`;
  const bodyScript = document.createElement("noscript");
  bodyScript.innerHTML = code;
  document.body.prepend(bodyScript);
}
$(document).ready(integrateGTM);
```

this way worked great for me, I hope it's the same for you